# Changed all objects value in list in object changed instead of only one

Tags: python, list, oop

I have problem with my program. When I try to change object value (which is in list) I changed all object's value in that list.
My code:

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def mirrorise(self, mirror):
        self.mirror = mirror
        if self.mirror.type == 'teleporterx':
            self.x -= (self.x-(self.mirror.x+self.mirror.x1/2))*2

class person(obj):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = [obj(self.x, self.y)]
    def mirrored(self, mirrors):
        self.count = 0
        self.mirrors = mirrors
        self.mens = 0
        for men in self.pos:
            self.mens += 1
        for mirror in self.mirrors:
            if self.count == 1:
                for men in range(self.mens):
                    self.pos.append(self.pos[men])
            self.count = 1
        self.count = 0
        for men in self.pos:
            men.mirrorise(self.mirrors[self.count])
            self.count += 1
            if self.mirrors[self.count-1] == self.mirrors[-1]:
                self.count = 0

class mirror:
    def __init__(self, x, y, x1, y1, type):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.type = type
```

After in code I call `person` object called I and two `mirror` objects called `mirr` and `mirr2` with type `teleportx`. When I write:

```
I.mirrored([mirr, mirr2])
```

it changes `x` for all objects in `I.pos`. If I write

```
I.pos[3].mirrorise(mirr)
```

it still changes all `x`. Even if I write:

```
I.pos[3].x -= (I.pos[3].x-(mirr2.x+mirr.x1/2))*2
```

it changes all values. So, is it some Python rule or I have mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding references to your one original `obj()` instance:

```
self.pos.append(self.pos[men])
```

That's not a copy; that's just another reference to the same object.

Create a *new* `obj()` instance instead:

```
self.pos.append(obj(self.pos[men].x, self.pos[men].y))
```

Comment: You are very fast. So fast that I can't accept answer (I have to wait 6 minutes) but it's correct.